# In Star Trek, is the commute time the same no matter how far the person transports?

Tags: star-trek

When people get beamed around in Star Trek, do(*should?*) all transports take just as long as each other, or does distance add to the commute time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**With the rare exception, the transporter moves matter at the speed of light with a maximum range of 40,000 kilometers. Under ideal conditions, all transports should take approximately the same amount of time due to the process required to detect, range, lock on, initiate pattern confinement, transport and reintegrate the subject.**

Major changes in transport time is almost always due to variables in the sequence of transport, disruption in the signal, interruption in the transport, strong electromagnetic disturbances or anti-transporter technology. The maximum distance of transport is well within one light second, so there should be no appreciable differences (to human senses) in transport time and shorter ranges. Of course, a computer could calculate the differences under ideal conditions, unless requested I won't.

Transport using technologies other than the Federation may have slightly different protocols and transport times, but transporter technology is fairly homogeneous in the Alpha Quadrant with very few exceptions.

> During the 22nd century, standard Earth transporter systems had a range of 10,000 kilometers; however, by the 24th century, standard transporter systems maximum range was about 40,000 kilometers, though a special type of transport, called subspace transport could beam over several light years. (ENT: "Rajiin"; TNG: "A Matter Of Honor", "Bloodlines")
>
> Gary Seven's mysterious sponsors on the Assigners' planet possessed transporter technology with a range of at least a thousand light years according to Spock. Scotty later noted that Seven's beam was so powerful it fused all of recording circuits, and therefore he could not say exactly how far it transported Seven, or even whether it transported him through time. Exactly how they achieved this effect remains unknown, since there has been no subsequent contact with them, and they hide their entire homeworld in some fashion. There were, however, other indications that their technology was considerably advanced beyond that of the 23rd century Federation. (TOS: "Assignment: Earth")

**--[Memory Alpha > Transporter > Range](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transporter)**

Comment: to a very good approximation, the speed of light is 300,000 km/sec, so each 300km would take an additional millisecond. Interesting side-note: 40,000km is pretty low: its nearly the height of a geostationary orbit around Earth, ~37000 km, which a ship would need to be in to stay in constant radio with a landing party. For a larger planet it would be well outside transporter range...

Comment: Do you have a citation for *c* being the transport speed and the 40,000km range limit?

Comment: Gary Seven in "Assignment: Earth" transported from at least 1000 light-years away.  One would presume that that didn't take a thousand years, so it must have been faster than light.  That must be one of the few exceptions.

Comment: how can Scotty transport to/from a ship in warp then? Oh, and he can manage it across most of the galaxy see [transwarp beaming](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Transwarp_beaming).

Comment: Star Trek routinely broke its own laws regarding their technology, often as an element of story telling i.e. "doing the impossible." Star Trek 2009 did quite a bit of that canon violation. It is the exception not the rule. Until they decide it is the rule.

Comment: Not strictly, easiest to explain it as being beyond federation science during the series, a lot of stuff in Star Trek 2009 features time travel from the future so.